# When can we expect a Wi-Fi hot-spot feature for Nokia Lumia 800?

Tags: lumia, internet-sharing

Windows Phone 7.5 has the Wi-Fi hotspot feature. But Nokia Lumia 800 seems to be an exception to this. A Wi-Fi hotspot is a great feature to use while on the move.

Rumors has that there'll be a patch released for Nokia Lumia 800 that will enable this feature on the phone. When is it going to happen (if it is ever going to happen)? Is there any official announcement by Nokia or Microsoft on this?

Comment: Should be out for a while now. Have it on my Lumia 800 now. Exact release date could be different per country.

Answer (score 3):

[Tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering) is coming [soon with a firmware update](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/03/16/tethering-support-coming-to-nokia-lumia-800-and-lumia-710/).

There is no date announced yet for this update. The Lumia 900 already has tethering support, so my guess is that it shouldn't take too long now.

Comment: Now announced: http://bit.ly/NXqPPT

Answer (score 2):

It is available now via the Tango update in most locations. You can check your carriers status here:
http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/lumia/